# google device find locked a galaxy tab 8 at walmart

Tags: google-account

Ok, that title might cause a wt? well its not as it seems to be.

About a week ago I was at a restaurant and went to write a review via google map. Well just before typing in my review I noticed that my display icon and screen name had been change to something..well that I wouldn't use. so next I had google ping the device and saw it was at a local wal mart.  hmmm kids must have my tablet, so finshed eating and went to Walmart.

when I get there I rang device remotely and wasn't hearing it or seeing anyone I knew react. so I figured i'll just lock it and go home and check to see if my tablet is at home. got home and hmmm, my device is at home. powered it up and noticed that I have a tab 4 not an 8. looked back at my phone and saw Walmart wifi and 100% battery, didn't notice battery state first time. so back to Walmart knowing that its a display on my account.

Checked phone area in front, no tabs, went back to electronics and found it.

I let the manager know about things and tried to unlock device but I couldn't.

I don't feel too bad that its a store device, but was wondering how are they going to unlock that device.
Also anyone know of a way for me to kick that device off of my google account?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense! How did your account end up on a random device in Walmart??

Did you set it up that way?

Answer (score 0):

> how are they going to unlock that device.

Starting from Android 4.0 and up, when locking a device using *find my device* it will not give you the option to choose a password, rather when unlocking the device you will have to enter the regular password/pattern that was used on the device till now. Therefore, all they have to do, is enter the password they always used.

If however, there was no password till then, and when locking the device, you chose a password, then they will have an issue, and they'll probably have to use some other method to enter.

> Also anyone know of a way for me to kick that device off of my google account?

Being that your account was registered with a public device, I'd suggest you wipe the device using [*find my device*](http://Android.com/find). Just log in, and choose the option to erase everything on the device.